# Increase a number by 50 instead of 1 using the increment operator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to increase a number using the increment `++` operator. But I don't want to add 1 every time the function executes. I need the number to raise by 50 each time the function executes. How do I do this?

I get an error when I try

```
x++y(x base number, y is 50) or x++50
```

Comment: Use the `+=` operator. `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y`. So your code would look like `x += 50`.

Comment: Suggest going back and looking over basic JS tutorials again.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change how much `++` will increment a number.

However, you could use `x += 50` which is shorthand for `x = x + 50`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 0;
  while (num < 500)
  {
    num += 50;
    document.write(num);
  }
```

Comment: `num = num += 50` breaks down to `num = num = num + 50`, why assign `num` twice?

Comment: Well it could be left as just num += 50; I wanted him to see how the incrementing works.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I wasn't one of the downvoters, just curious.

Comment: I actually get amazed at the downvoters. This actually solves the problem so why does it attract downvoters. I guess it's a rule of life "Not wanting others to reach the top - one messy part of life". Anyway, the aim was to help solve the problem which I've done. Let 'em haters keep hating!

Comment: Downvoters are not "haters". Some of them like correct solutions, and your initial solution of "num = num += 50" was just wrong, and deserves a downvote for that reason. More basically, though, if the criteria for a downvote is "not useful", this answer (and all the others) is not useful in the sense that the `+=` operator is covered in every JS intro ever written, and is triivally Googleable (search for "JavaScript increment'). Actually, it's worse than not useful, because it promotes and encourages trivial questions that show no research effort whatsoever.

Comment: Okay, accepted. I thought the former will make the 'asker' of the question see (visually not 'programmatically') how to add a `50` anytime the iteration occurs. Thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to do `x=x+50` this takes the value of x and then adds 50 to it.

**EDIT:** You can also use `x+=50`